# when i try to build the add migration method on the nuget package console that appears to me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-migration

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\tariq\Pictures\Screenshots\project(mvc)\project(mvc)\appsettings.json'.
Unable to create an object of type 'MVCdemoDBcontext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I tried to debug this in appjason.cs
"MVCdemoConnectionString": "server=TARIQ\MSSQLSERVER01;database=MVCdemoDB;Trusted_connection=true"
and it shows me that error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDZ8f.png)